# Enabling http2 on wildfly 10, standalone.conf

Tags: wildfly, http2

I've followed the step by step tutorial [here](http://undertow.io/blog/2015/03/26/HTTP2-In-Wildfly.html) but I didn't manage to make it work.

I edited standalone.conf which now looks like this

> ```
> if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
>    JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
>    JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
>
> else
>    echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
>
> fi
>
> JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/bin/alpn-boot-8.1.6.v20151105.jar"
> ```

and when starting the server i get the error:

```
Jetty ALPN not found. HTTP2 and SPDY are not available. Please make sure Jetty ALPN is on the boot class path.
```

Do I have to configure wildflt so it takes standalone.conf into account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok since I'm on windows the steps are actually a bit different.

Just modify standalone.conf.bat instead of standalone.bat (edit the bat, not run it, in case you are as illiterate in that area as I am).

and add

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xbootclasspath/p:%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\alpn-boot-8.1.6.v20151105.jar"
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the APLN to the class boot path.

follow these steps

**figure out the jetty APLN version for your JDK version.**

type  *java -version* on your commandline
will get something like this

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode, sharing)
```

In this case, JDK “1.6.0_18” is installed on the computer.

Have a look at http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html to figure out which version of Jetty ALPN is required for your JVM version. Download the correct jar version from maven central(http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/alpn/alpn-boot/) and place it in the Wildfly bin directory.

**Add ALPN to the boot class path**

Edit standalone.conf and add the following line to the JAVA_OPTS environment variable (making appropriate substitutions for the ALPN version).

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/bin/alpn-boot-$ALPN_VERSION.jar
```

in my case my JDK was 1.8.0_131
and matching APLN was 8.1.11.v20170118.i downloaded it added it to the bin folder and adjusted the bootpath with

```
Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/bin/alpn-boot-8.1.11.v20170118.jar
```

**restart the jboss application server at last**

you will not be getting the APLN  error again.